# Rails 5 Parameters and to_h

Tags: parameters, ruby-on-rails-5, upgrade

We're in the process of upgrading to Rails 5.1.0 from Rails 4.2.2 and we've noticed that `.except!()` is no longer a method for Parameters. There is an `.except()` without the bang but that doesn't work in all of our cases. In the examples below `survey_params` is of the type `Parameter`.

```
@survey.update(survey_params.except!(:user_roles)) # Rails 4.2.2
```

The two solutions I came with are:

1. Make a throwaway variable to accept the results of an un-banged `.except()` like this:

   `clean_params = survey_params.except(:user_roles)`

And then use it in the update like so:

```
@survey.update(clean_params)
```

2. Use `.to_h` to convert it to a hash which seems to still have `.except!`

   `@survey.update(survey_params.to_h.except!(:user_roles))`

Both work but I'm wondering if one is better than the other or is there a better way than either of these solutions? Because both feel kind of like bandaid fixes.